# Logging in Python with different levels

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

For some reason I can't get both of these to work at the same time.  Only the first one applies.  Does any one know why?

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/debug2.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/critical.log',level=logging.CRITICAL)
```

Cant I have different log files for different levels?  This is Python 2.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have one logger object and you are changing its output file and level to need to create two logger objects and configure them separately.

Example from the [helps](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook):

```
import logging
# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')

# Now, define a couple of other loggers which might represent areas in your
# application:

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```